# Python - PHP save base64 to image

Tags: php, python

Good day. Can somebody help me of my problem. I'm new in python and php. I want to send the base64 encoded image to my php server. But i don't know what happen to my php script.

The encoded data send properly to php script and save the newImage.jpg to directory c:/image/newImage.jpg. But when i try to preview the newImage.jpg, it says "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupt or is to large"

The problem is how i can save the image properly. 
Any comments and suggestion is very appreciated.

Sorry for my english. Thank you.

PHP script:

```
<?php
    $encodedString = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['test']);
    $decoded=base64_decode($encodedString);
    file_put_contents('c:/image/1/newImage.JPG',$decoded);
?>
```

Python script:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from urllib import urlencode

url = 'http://192.168.5.165/server/php/try2.php'
encoded = urllib.quote(open("c:/image/1.jpg", "rb").read().encode("base64"))

data = {'test': encoded}
encoded_data = urlencode(data)

website = urllib2.urlopen(url, encoded_data)
print website.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code you need to [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) the data in `$_POST['test']` and then `base64_decode()` it. You don't need to replace spaces with '+' (which is back-to-front anyway).

In Python, you only need to `urlencode()`, you don't need to `urllib.quote()` as well.

So your PHP can be:

```
<?php
    $decoded = base64_decode(urldecode($_POST['test']));
    file_put_contents('c:/image/1/newImage.JPG',$decoded);
?>
```

And your Python code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from urllib import urlencode

url = 'http://192.168.5.165/server/php/try2.php'
encoded = open("c:/image/1.jpg", "rb").read().encode("base64")

data = {'test': encoded}
encoded_data = urlencode(data)

website = urllib2.urlopen(url, encoded_data)
print website.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

i am a lazy guy but i will help change to this in the php

```
<?php
    $encodedString = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['test']);
    $decoded=base64_decode($encodedString);
    $decoded=imagecreatefromstring($decoded);
    imagejpg($decoded, "temp.jpg");
    copy("temp.jpg",'c:/image/1/newImage.JPG');
?>
```

the problem is simple you are trying to save an object that is not yet a image in to a file, so first make an image set it as a temp image, then copy it to where you want it to go.